# Need help understanding function bind when dealing with objects

Tags: javascript

```
function theFunction() {
    console.log(this.some)
}

//Case 1
var object = {
    aFun:theFunction.bind({some: 'case 1'})
}

//Case 2
var object2 = {
    aFun:theFunction
}
object2.aFun.bind({some: 'case 2'});
object.aFun();
object2.aFun();
```

The above returns

```
case 1
undefined
```

I would expect it to be

```
case 1
case 2
```

Why is this working differently than I would expect?  I have ways to work around this issue.  I'm mostly looking into why this works this way.

Comment: `object2.aFun = object2.aFun.bind({some: 'case 2'});`

Comment: `bind` *returns* a function. It doesn't modify one in place. If you changed it to `object2.aFun = object2.aFun.bind({some: 'case 2'})` then it would work as you expect.

Comment: @MikeC if you put your response as an answer I will accept it.  Thank you that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) *returns a copy* of a function with `this` set to the value of the first argument rather than modifying the function directly.

To get the result you expected, you would change

```
object2.aFun.bind({some: 'case 2'})
```

into

```
object2.aFun = object2.aFun.bind({some: 'case 2'})
```